# How to do conditional average?

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I want to calculate average result by post_author. Here's my code:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN post_author = 1 THEN post_content ELSE 0 END )as avg
```

It got a result of 100 on 2 records (100, 66.7) which should be 83.35
Where things went wrong?

Comment: are post_auther and post_content numeric columns?

Comment: What was wrong using `group by post_author` for `avg` calculation?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: post_auther is numeric, post_content not. @Ravinder --I need to group by other things.

Comment: If `post_content` is *not numeric*, then why are you using it to calculate `avg`?

Comment: this column is not used for this post_type. So, I think I can just store things here for easier query. Otherwise I have to join other table to do the query

Answer (score 7):

You can just drop the `else` clause, so `NULL` is passed in:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN post_author = 1 THEN post_content END) as "avg"
```

Your query is setting unmatching values to `0` for the purposes of the average.  You want them ignored, so use `NULL`.

Comment: AVG(CASE WHEN post_author = 1 THEN post_content ELSE NULL END )as avg could make it more clear